# How to create a polygon in tkinter canvas using PIL library

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating polygons in tkinter canvas using canvas.create_polygon function.

```
label= canvas.create_polygon(list_of_points, fill='', outline='green', width=2)
```

I want to create same polygons using below PIL library function .

```
PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon(xy, fill=None, outline=None)
```

Is it possible to draw polygon inside canvas using PIL function?

Comment: No, PIL is for creating images. However, you can use PIL to create an image, and then you can place the image on a canvas. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: If I add the code to question, it will be clear.

Comment: I want to create polygon from list_of_points using PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon function instead of canvas.create_polygon

Comment: @BryanOakley here is the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you clarified your question with this:

> I want to create polygon from list_of_points using PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon function instead of canvas.create_polygon

You cannot use PIL to create objects directly on tkinter widgets. You can only use PIL to create images. You can then place that image on a canvas. However, PIL itself doesn't know anything about tkinter widgets.

Comment: Okay, How to place that image on canvas? Any idea?

Comment: @john: read the documentation, or search this site. There must be hundreds of examples.

Comment: Facing the error:  in func_draw_polygon
    label=draw.polygon(list_of_points)
NameError: global name 'draw' is not defined